# How to compute the mean of a 2D array with ROI?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, mean

I have an array `I` and its ROI (Region of Interesting). Its ROI has two value 1 and 0.

My task is that computes the mean of these values in the array, such that their ROI is bigger than 0.

For example,

```
I=[1,2,3
   4,5,6
   7,8,9]
ROI=[0,1,1
     1,0,0
     0,0,1]
```

The mean will be **mean(2,3,4,9)=18/4=4.5**

This is my code, however, it has warning if the all values in ROI are zero. For example

```
ROI=[0,0,0
     0,0,0
     0,0,0]
```

How can I solve it? I am using python2.7 and getting error below:

> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:55: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
>     warnings.warn("Mean of empty slice.", RuntimeWarning)

```
mask=ROI>0
if len(mask)>0:
   mean_ROI=I(mask)
```

Comment: Post sample data and the code that reproduces that RuntimeWarning?

Comment: Thank Divakar. I updated it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check the case:

```
if ROI.any():
    mean = I[ROI > 0].mean()
else:
    mean = 0
```

Or in an one liner using ternary:

```
mean = I[ROI > 0].mean() if ROI.any() else 0
```

Comment: ROI is int32 type. Is it correct to use if ROI.any()? I am using python 2.7

Comment: Is there any case that you would have numbers greater than 1 that you don't want to consider in the mean? e.g. `ROI = [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 7, 0, 1]`

Comment: Yes, the ROI is not only 1. In my example, I just show simple case, But ROI is from 0 to 10. I just want to compute mean of ROI from 1 to 10

Comment: And I am using python 2.7. So it is better using np.mean() instead of .mean()

Comment: Then first of all change `I[ROI == 1]` to `I[ROI > 0]`. In this case the `np.mean()` and the `<variable>.mean()` is the same numpy function. Python doesn't have a built-in mean function AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

To remove warning use:

```
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=RuntimeWarning)
    mymean = np.mean([i for i, j in zip(I, ROI) if j])
    print(mymean)
```